# Nativescript UI not updating when adding or removing css classes programmatically

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I am facing problems in updating UI when adding or deleting classes to elements on page.
I am trying to make an alternative to nativescript-dom plugin which is now not working on ns6.

main-page.ts

```
import { TOGGLECLASS, checkChildren } from "./common";

//hide / unhide extraneous fields
export function toggleHidden() {    
    checkChildren(TOGGLECLASS, page, "toHide", "hidden");
}
```

main-page.xml

```
<ActionItem id="settbtnfrm" tap="toggleHidden" icon="~/images/sett.png" visibility="visible"></ActionItem> <!-- Settings -->
```

common.ts

```
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export const TOGGLECLASS = 1, ADDCLASS = 2, DELETECLASS = 3;

export function checkChildren(method: number, vi:View, getterClasName:string, clasName:string) {
    vi.eachChildView((vii) => {
        if(vii.cssClasses.has(getterClasName)) {

            if(method == TOGGLECLASS) {
                if(vii.cssClasses.has(clasName)) {
                    vii.cssClasses.delete(clasName);
                } else {
                    vii.cssClasses.add(clasName);
                }
            } else if(method == ADDCLASS) {
                if(vii.cssClasses.has(clasName)) {
                } else {
                    vii.cssClasses.add(clasName);
                }
            } else if(method == DELETECLASS) {
                if(vii.cssClasses.has(clasName)) {
                    vii.cssClasses.delete(clasName);
                }
            }

        }
        checkChildren(method, vii, getterClasName, clasName);
        return true;
    });
}
```

This code deletes or adds classes.
I can check it by console.log(vii.cssClasses.has(clasName));
This returns correct true false on console but does not update actual UI.
The elements with css class toHide should be hidden and unhidden.

Sample element to hide unhide in main-page.xml

```
<GridLayout columns="*, 100, auto, auto" rows="*" class="toHide hidden">
            <Label col="0" class="lbl lft" text="Jumbo Rate" textWrap="true" />
            <TextField col="1" hint="Jumbo" text="{{ rateJumbo }}" keyboardType="number" editable="true" />
            <Button col="2" text="-" objtoset="rateJumbo" class="btn btn-outline btn-rounded-sm mnb1" tap="reduceVal" changeVal="1" />
            <Button col="3" text="+" objtoset="rateJumbo" class="btn btn-outline btn-rounded-sm mnb2" tap="increaseVal" changeVal="1" />

        </GridLayout>
```

Please help I am not so good in NativeScript but like this framework alot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of controlling visibility is to use the visibility attribute with a  conditional statement, and then set the associated binding variable, such as,

in xml:

```
<Label class="label" text="Label Text"  visibility="{{ showLabel ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" />
```

in js:

```
viewModel.set("showLabel", "true");
```

If you really want to control the class, then you could do something like,

```
<Label class="{{ showLabel ? 'labelShow' : 'labelHide' }}" text="Label Text"  />
```

This may be somewhat simpler than the approach you're taking now.

Comment: Thank you David. This is surely a simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to use `cssClasses` property, the easiest way to do is by passing all your class names separated by space to `className` property.

Internally the framework listens for changes on `className`, parse it and store them in `cssClasses` set and trigger an UI update.

But in case if you think playing with `className` is hard, you would rather prefer using `cssClasses` then you should call the private method `._onCssStateChange()` on the view instance to update UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label row="1" col="1" [ngClass]="{'price-active' : isActive}" class="price" [text]="price"></Label>

.price {
        horizontal-align: right;
        font-size: 16;
        color: $dark-green;

        &.price-active {
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    }
```